# POI failure java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization

Tags: java, xml

POI failure

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization:when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.getEntityResolver()Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;" the class loader (instance of com/newatlanta/servletexec/ApplClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/xml/sax/XMLReader have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/EntityResolver used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:343)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:396)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.<init>(ContentTypeManager.java:120)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.<init>(ZipContentTypeManager.java:63)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:147)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.Package.getParts(Package.java:598)
    at org.openxml4j.opc.Package.open(Package.java:227)
```

I meet the issue when I was using XMLBean on ServletExec. How can I solve it?

Comment: After i remove the xercesImpl-jar i get the new exception:PanelXLReport 2013-11-26 17:01:15 POI failure  java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
 when resolving interface method "org.xml.sax.XMLReader.setEntityResolver(Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;)V" 
 the class loader (instance of com/newatlanta/servletexec/ApplClassLoader) of the current class, org/dom4j/io/SAXReader, 
 and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, org/xml/sax/XMLReader, have different Class objects for the type
 org/xml/sax/EntityResolver used in the signature

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `xercesImpl-jar` from classpath of your application and re deploy it. Try that if any other issues raises due to removing the particular jar.Then do not remove the jar.Just extract the jar and remove the `org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser`  class file from `xercesImpl-jar` which gets conflicts and convert the remaining class file into jar and load it to the classpath.It would help you to solve the Linkage Error.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, after remove the xercesImpl -jar. I get the new exception:PanelXLReport 2013-11-26 17:01:15 POI failure  java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
 when resolving interface method "org.xml.sax.XMLReader.setEntityResolver(Lorg/xml/sax/EntityResolver;)V" 
 the class loader (instance of com/newatlanta/servletexec/ApplClassLoader) of the current class, org/dom4j/io/SAXReader, 
 and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, org/xml/sax/XMLReader, have different Class objects for the type
 org/xml/sax/EntityResolver used in the signature

Comment: remove the `dom4j-1.3.jar` mate it would help you .

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are deploying the xerces-parser along with your application although it is already part of the server - and the server seems to choke on that. Try removing the xercesImpl-jar from your deployment, e.g. in case of maven set its scope to `provided`.